# SFTP server disconnect and SpringBoot application stops polling the server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have an application in Spring Boot using Spring Integration.
I need to poll a SFTP server for new files regulary, a few times a day. For this we have a cron expression

```
0 0 6,8,10,15,22 * * *
```

Nothing strange there.
The issue I am experiencing is that after 5 minutes from conencting to the SFTP server the connection is closed.
I have tried some different settings but without result.
This is my class

```
@Configuration public class SftpConfig {

    @Value("${sftp.host}")
    private String sftpHost;

    @Value("${sftp.port:22}")
    private int sftpPort;

    @Value("${sftp.user}")
    private String sftpUser;

    @Value("${sftp.password}")
    private String sftpPasword;

    @Value("${directory.remote.source}")
    private String remoteSourceDirectory;

    @Value("${directory.local.storage}")
    private String localStorageDirectory;

    @Value("${file.download.filter}")
    private String downloadFilter;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteSourceDirectory);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(downloadFilter));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "${sftp.poller}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(localStorageDirectory));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler resultFileHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                LOGGER.info((String) message.toString());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I have tried to comment the ChashingSessionFactory out and just return the factory with sharedSession set to true and false.
I have tried to set sharedSession to true and add sessionCasheSize to 10

```
CachingSessionFactory cachedSession = new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory, 10);
cachedSession.setSessionWaitTimeout(1000);
return cachedSession;
```

The connection is allways closed after some time, often 5 minutes. So I suspect that the remote server has a timeout set.

As I understand it, the SFTP bean is created at startup, and the connection is created at first poll after startup.
How do I keep the connection alive?

Or maybe I should just create the session at each poll, and kill it when I am done? How do I do that?
Is that something that eats memory from the disc?

I need an application that just keeps going without any big efforts.
Thank you for your input and answers.`

*************************EDIT*************************
I have enabled DEBUG on jcraft logs but I only get info logs. Other than that it doesn't log much

```
2021-06-10 12:25:02.612  INFO 32552 --- [aron.se session] com.jcraft.jsch : Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to End of IO Stream Read
2021-06-10 12:25:02.612  INFO 32552 --- [aron.se session] com.jcraft.jsch : Disconnecting from sftp.XX.XX port 22
```

Then it only says

```
GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=cf75ef7e-1973-71e9-5051-5d4bdbdd4395, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623322200008}]
```

when trying to poll the SFTP-server again.
No files are fetched from the server and I have to reboot the whole application to make it work again.

*************************EDIT 2*************************

```
2021-06-10 13:25:02.971  INFO 26824 --- [aron.se session] com.jcraft.jsch : Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to End of IO Stream Read
2021-06-10 13:25:02.972  INFO 26824 --- [aron.se session] com.jcraft.jsch : Disconnecting from sftp.XX.XX port 22
2021-06-10 13:30:00.011 DEBUG 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
2021-06-10 13:30:00.014 DEBUG 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'fromSftpChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
2021-06-10 13:30:00.014 DEBUG 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] .i.h.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : bean 'sftpConfig.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator.handler' for component 'sftpConfig.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator' received message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
2021-06-10 13:30:00.015  INFO 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] se.XX.YY.sftp.SftpConfig       : GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
2021-06-10 13:30:00.016 DEBUG 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] .i.h.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : handler 'bean 'sftpConfig.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator.handler' for component 'sftpConfig.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator'' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
2021-06-10 13:30:00.016 DEBUG 26824 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'fromSftpChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:\Temp\file.xml, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.XX.XX:22, file_name=file.xml, file_remoteDirectory=/DropZone, file_originalFile=C:\Temp\file.xml, id=12e1f7a4-2d49-5499-2b6f-7ef41aca1c50, file_relativePath=file.xml, file_remoteFile=file.xml, timestamp=1623324600011}]
```

Comment: did you check if there is a firewall policy at the server? I have experienced this in my previous org.

Comment: Yes there is a timeout on the SFTP server. If I connect to the same server through WinSCP I get a connection reset after five minutes. So I think it is the same here.

Comment: what is the error you get? Can you show the logs by enabling debug logs?

Comment: Se my update Edit above for logs

Comment: I have added logging for org.springframework.integration too now too see if that works.

Comment: Make `DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false)` and use `CachingSessionFactory`. Saw similar error yesterday and after pocking around figured out that it is better to keep sessions connected and don't share the same one between processes: essentially don't let them die! This way it feels like SSH server understands that we are still connected and doesn't drop sockets. At least my experience...

Comment: You can also play with the `serverAliveInterval` or some other SSH properties. See `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` setters and their JavaDocs.

Comment: Thank you I will try use false and cashingSessionFactory.
I tried serverAliveInterval before but it didn't look like it fired. BUT I will try again for sure!
 MAybe it is some combination of some sort....
Thanks you for your input.